# why button not set text in mdpi and ldpi?

Tags: android

I am making button using java code but button take text in ldpi but not in mdpi and hdpi 
   i am using this code

```
objlinear = new LinearLayout(this);
    llinner = new LinearLayout(this);
    objlinear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    llinner.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams txtLayoutParams =
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
               ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
               ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    llinner.setLayoutParams(txtLayoutParams);

    createButton();
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
   setContentView(objlinear,lp);
   Toast.makeText(this, "check", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}



private void createButton() {
            //int size = list.size();
    for (int index = 0; index <3; index++) {

        Button objwidgetbutton = new Button(this);



        LinearLayout.LayoutParams objlayoutbtnparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(250,30); // Verbose!

        objwidgetbutton.setText("hiii");

        llinner.addView(objwidgetbutton,objlayoutbtnparams);

    }
    objlinear.addView(llinner);

}
```

when running code in mdpi simple button is created but no text show on button

Comment: What do you mean by "running code in mdpi" ? In an emulator with a mdpi resolution ?

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `WRAP_CONTENT` for the height of your linear layouts.